# Refresh formula field in Process Builder?

Tags: formula, formula-field, process-builder

I've just run into an interesting Process Builder issue in a client Professional org. I have reproduced it in a small scale on my dev org. Here is a nonsensical minimal example:

- I added two text fields to Account called **ChangeThis** and **CopiedHere**.
- I added a formula field to Account called **EchoesHere** that simply equals the value of **ChangeThis**.
- I created a Process that is set not to allow recursion and triggers on edit of Account. The first and only condition is that **ChangeThis** has changed.
- The first action is to update **ChangeThis** to concatenate "!!!" to the end of the same field.
- The second action (within the same condition) is to update **CopiedHere** to equal **EchoesHere**.

So now, if I edit **ChangeThis** to equal "Hello" in the UI and save, I get:

- **ChangeThis**: Hello!!!
- **EchoesHere**: Hello!!!
- **CopiedHere**: Hello

So evidently Process Builder is only retrieving the formula field value at the beginning of the process, rather than calculating it "live" after any updates. Is there any way to force Builder to refresh the formula field mid-process?

Is this "working as intended"?

Answer (score 1):

It is working as intended.

Since in the process builder, you are updating **CopiedHere** to equal **EchoesHere**. and **EchoesHere** is the formula field, so its value will be reflected after committing of data.

So, during middle of execution **EchoesHere** = Hello, so as **CopiedHere** also
and after committing,

**EchoesHere** = Hello!!!  (which is same as **ChangeThis**)

and naturally **CopiedHere** = Hello (because of formula field condition)

Refer [Triggers and Order of Execution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm)

Hope it makes sense!

Comment: Yes I'm familiar with order of execution but formula fields are not actually data stored in the DB so their behaviour is undefined in the order of execution. My colleague made the reasonable assumption that after updating a field in Process Builder, requesting the value of a formula field would calculate that value live based on the updated value. This left us stumped for weeks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Just like the workflow field update operation, all field operations behave as if they were performed simultaneously. Multiple updates to the same field in the same workflow update will have undefined behavior. To get the desired output, you'd have to use recursion.

If you read the logs, you'll see that the engine actually evaluates all rules, then calculates all updates, and finally apply all changes, followed by any recursion, if specified.

Comment: It seems that Process Builder generates very obfuscated logs. I've been trying to follow them but I can't make heads or tails of it. Do you have a suggestion for a guide to interpreting those logs?

In Process Builder it does seem to be the case that updating a field on the current record and then reading its value will show you the updated value. And we're always told that formula fields are "live" values calculated on the fly. So it just comes as a surprise that those fields are not as "live" as expected in Process Builder.

Comment: @CharlesT Formulas are "live" from the moment they're loaded from the database. The key here is *loaded from the database*. They're not recalculated in memory every time a field changes during a transaction, only at certain key phases in a transaction. That naturally has some confusing side effects, particularly with PB/workflows, but that's how the system works today. As for debugging PB, let me see if I can't come up with some more details for you.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I know that Apex has a "recalculate formula" function for formula fields... it would be nice if PB could have that too.

Comment: @CharlesT That's actually the purpose of allowing recursion, because the values would be updated after a field update.

Comment: Unfortunately we're in a situation where a Professional Edition client has a maximum of 5 active Process Builders so we end up with a very long chain of conditions and actions in any one Process. Inevitably, allowing recursion causes an infinite loop and it fails.